# TypeError: App_1.apiUrl is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm confused as to why a function I export from one React TypeScript module fails when imported into another module.

```
export const apiUrl = () : string => (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') ?
    "https://localhost:5001" : "https://my.azure.site.net";
```

I'm aware this is not the best way to set environment-specific info but it seemed like an expedient way to do this as a quick way to test the Azure service.

When I import `apiUrl` into other modules I get the `TypeError`.

```
import { apiUrl } from './App';
console.log(apiUrl());
```

> TypeError: App_1.apiUrl is not a function. (In 'App_1.apiUrl()', 'App_1.apiUrl' is undefined)

And the function is undefined. So much for expedience. I've tried a couple of permutations, including exporting a const string:

```
export const apiUrl = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') ? "https://localhost:5001" : "https://my.azure.site.net";
```

In all cases the imported object is `undefined`.

Update: I've established that if I use the string or method inside a class method then it works, i.e. when I call it in the `componentDidMount` method. What am I missing about scope here?

Comment: Definitely odd. to Hazard a quick guess, perhaps you weren't targeting the right module format. named exports  exported from common JS modules is fraught with uncertainty and each level of your tool chain may handle it differently.

Comment: I advise that you `console.table(App_1)` and see what's on it, does it contain `default` does it contain an `__esModule` property?